# ¿Como traducir "dial-up modem" al español?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

Tengo un duda sobre cómo traducir correctamente **dial-up modem**. Según mi traducción sería:

*Conexión por modem*.

Pero buscando en google el puro término **dial-up** me sale con **Conexión por línea conmutada**, lo cual es una conexión a internet donde el cliente utiliza el modem.

Entonces, mi traducción como *Conexión por modem* es correcta? O hay una traducción mejor para esta palabra?

Comment: *dial-up* es marcar o marcación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es correcto decir **conexión por módem**. Módem es un anglicismo aceptado en español.

Sin embargo, es de mencionar que los servicios de Internet por cable también utilizan un módem. Así que, dependiendo de el contexto completo, sea necesario decir *Conexión por **módem** telefónico*, *conexión por **módem** de línea conmutada*; al contrario de *conexión por **cable-módem*** o *conexión por **cable módem***.

La palabra **cablemódem** también se utiliza aunque no aparece en el DRAE.

Comment: La web de [IATE](http://iate.europa.eu/) también traduce "dial-up modem" como "conexión por módem".

Comment: La traducción literal sería **módem de acceso telefónico**. Dependiendo del contexto pienso que bastaría **conexión por módem**